# Is it possible to run an async task using a System.Threading.Timer?

Tags: c#, .net

So I'm using a threading timer and want to run a task every 10 seconds. Inside this async task method I run other tasks inside it. I tried doing this with a System.Threading.Timer.

```
_taskTimer = new Timer(statusChecker.CheckStatus, autoEvent, 1000, 250);
```

It seems that you can't await the function you assign to it. Is there a work around for this? I've googled the question multiple times, but all that comes up is irrelevant SO posts about nonasync solutions.

Comment: Welcome to the community toked. Please insert more of you code, so we can understand a bit better what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need the timer for this use case. Here's one way to continuously call a function every x seconds (in a console program):

```
class Program
{
    static Task statusCheckingTask;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        statusCheckingTask = CheckStatusTask(10);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static async Task CheckStatusTask(int delayInSeconds)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            await CheckStatus();
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(delayInSeconds));
        }
    }

    static async Task CheckStatus()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Checking status...");
        await Task.FromResult(0);
    }

}
```

Comment: if `CheckStatus();` will run for 2 seconds, it will be called every 12 seconds:\

Comment: You're right, that is a difference with a regular timer.

Comment: Your application may terminate before `statusCheckingTask` finishes.

Comment: Why `while (true)`? That means that the app has to crash to close.

Comment: @Enigmativity what makes you say that? Not in an interactive application at least, I'm not sure about a windows service or web app though.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fire status checking every 250 ms, regardless of previous attempt result, use this:

```
while (true)
{
    Task.Run(() => statusChecker.CheckStatus(autoEvent));

    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(250));
}
```

If you want to fire status checking only when previous attempt is finished, use this:

```
while (true)
{
    await statusChecker.CheckStatus(autoEvent);

    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(250));
}
```

Both cases assume, that `statusChecker.CheckStatus` returns a `Task` object, e.g.:

```
public async Task CheckStatus(object autoEvent)
{
    // some async status checking
}
```

Comment: Why `while (true)`? That means that the app has to crash to close.

Comment: @Enigmativity: Actually, it depends on what thread executes this code - background thread will be terminated on main thread exit. But I agree, that next step is to add `CancellationToken`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using Microsoft's Reactive Framework (NuGet "System.Reactive" and add `using System.Reactive.Linq;`) and then you can do this:

```
IObservable<bool> query =
    from n in Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10.0))
    from s in Observable.FromAsync(() => statusChecker.CheckStatus())
    select s;

IDisposable subscription =
    query.Subscribe(status =>
    {
        /* Do something with each `status` as it arrives */
    });
```

This assumes that `.CheckStatus()` returns `Task<bool>`.

It's all done with background threads and is async. Just call `subscription.Dispose()` to stop the interval timer. Simple.